# Stylized punctuation marks for mathematical formulas

Tags: symbols, punctuation, mathematics

I'm looking for a a set of stylized punctuation marks for use in mathematical formulas. Package `stix` has a symbol `\typecolon` that looks like this [image: <code>stix</code>'s <code>\typecolon</code>] This is just the kind of thing I am looking for, but is there a matching set of punctuation marks? I'm especially interested in a matching comma.

EDIT: Just to make it absolutely clear: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)) is a **colon**, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon) is a **semicolon**, and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma) is a **comma**. I'm especially interested in a *comma* that has the same look as the `stix` *colon* shown above. Alternatively, I'll be satisfied to find a *comma* and a *colon* (as two separate symbols, specifically *not* a *semicolon*) that have a different look, as long as their looks match each other, and as long as they stand out and don't look "normal".

Comment: That is Z notation,  ctan has some packages for that see for example http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/zed-csp/zed2e.pdf  you may be able to borrow more symbols even if you are not using Z

Comment: I agree totally with David Carlisle: [0000 2982] Z NOTATION TYPE COLON from this notes pag: 28: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n3187.pdf and you can see also this old question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309432/colon-like-symbol-with-circles-instead-of-dots/309502

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It doesn't look like the Z notation have a stylized comma, which is what I am interested in particular.

Comment: @Sebastiano: It doesn't look like the Z notation have a stylized comma, which is what I am interested in particular.

Comment: @EvanAad Excuse me: do you want find a circle up and a `,` down? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I want to find a hollow [comma](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgola), or, alternatively, a set of punctuation marks that includes a [colon](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Due_punti) and a comma that are different than usual and that stand-out more that usual.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125578/outline-text-using-truetype-fonts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you like the comma (and other punctuation marks) from the blackboard bold font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\typecomma}{\text{\textbb{,}}}
\newcommand{\typesemi}{\text{\textbb{;}}}
\newcommand{\typeperiod}{\text{\textbb{.}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1=1 \typecomma
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
2=2 \typesemi
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
3=3 \typeperiod
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My sincere compliments. Bravissimo.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, you can also set up the characters, such that when you type `,;.` in math mode, the stylized versions of the glyphs appear in the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbold}

% Macros to access the old glyphs
\mathchardef\normalcomma=\mathcode`,
\mathchardef\normalsemicolon=\mathcode`;
\mathchardef\normalperiod=\mathcode`.

% Map bbold glyphs to characters
\DeclareSymbolFont{bboldletters}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{bboldletters}{"2C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{;}{\mathpunct}{bboldletters}{"3B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord  }{bboldletters}{"2E}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \normalcomma     &\to , \\
    \normalsemicolon &\to ; \\
    \normalperiod    &\to .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can also map the `bbold` glyphs to commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbold}

% Map bbold glyphs to commands
\DeclareSymbolFont{bboldletters}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bboldcomma    }{\mathpunct}{bboldletters}{"2C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bboldsemicolon}{\mathpunct}{bboldletters}{"3B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bboldperiod   }{\mathord  }{bboldletters}{"2E}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \bboldcomma     &\to , \\
    \bboldsemicolon &\to ; \\
    \bboldperiod    &\to .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This could be very convenient in some circumstance. However, in my particular case, the reason why I need the stylized versions is precisely because I need to distinguish them from their ordinary counterparts which are used in the same formula.