# Strange behaviour in importing symbols from stix package

Tags: symbols, stix

I was importing symbols from the `stix` package (brackets in particular) following the directives given [here on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254618/how-to-use-only-selected-math-symbols-of-the-stix-fonts) when something really strange happend, which I presume has to deal with the font encoding `LS2`. In particular I imported the sequent symbols, succesfully

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
    \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBrace}{\mathopen}{largesymbols}{"E8}{largesymbols}{"0E}
    \DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBrace}{\mathclose}{largesymbols}{"E9}{largesymbols}{"0F}
    \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBrack}{\mathopen}{largesymbols}{"E0}{largesymbols}{"06}
    \DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBrack}{\mathclose}{largesymbols}{"E1}{largesymbols}{"07}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsstix}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
    \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrbrak}{\mathopen}{largesymbolsstix}{"EE}{largesymbolsstix}{"14}
    \DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrbrak}{\mathclose}{largesymbolsstix}{"EF}{largesymbolsstix}{"15}
```

which are exactly what I want. But the problem is that all the basic latex symbols seem to be gone; a simple code, with a sum, and some partial derivatives, for example, gives this bad outcome

[image]

where the right symbol now are only the two imported brace `\lBrace` and `\rBrace`. Now, if I comment the part in which I declare the symbols

```
    \DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
    \DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
%   \DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
%       \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBrace}{\mathopen}{largesymbols}{"E8}{largesymbols}{"0E}
%       \DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBrace}{\mathclose}{largesymbols}{"E9}{largesymbols}{"0F}
%       \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBrack}{\mathopen}{largesymbols}{"E0}{largesymbols}{"06}
%       \DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBrack}{\mathclose}{largesymbols}{"E1}{largesymbols}{"07}
%   \DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsstix}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
%       \DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrbrak}{\mathopen}{largesymbolsstix}{"EE}{largesymbolsstix}{"14}
%       \DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrbrak}{\mathclose}{largesymbolsstix}{"EF}{largesymbolsstix}{"15}
```

everything is back to normality, but with no more the two brackets desired from the `stix` package (I replaced manually the two braces, otherwise it would have not compiled):

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

## EDIT:

I found that the true problem comes with the `\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}`, as there is already a default setup for the class `largesymbols`, which is `\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}`. But the problem still stands still, as the one exclude the other. How can I use those symbols along with the standard latex ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I replaced your `largesymbols` with `largesymbolsstix` and gave it a spin.  Is this sufficient?

(As noted in the OP's edit, `largesymbols` is already employed by LaTeX)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\@noaccents}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsstix}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBrace}{\mathopen}{largesymbolsstix}{"E8}{largesymbolsstix}{"0E}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBrace}{\mathclose}{largesymbolsstix}{"E9}{largesymbolsstix}{"0F}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBrack}{\mathopen}{largesymbolsstix}{"E0}{largesymbolsstix}{"06}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBrack}{\mathclose}{largesymbolsstix}{"E1}{largesymbolsstix}{"07}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrbrak}{\mathopen}{largesymbolsstix}{"EE}{largesymbolsstix}{"14}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrbrak}{\mathclose}{largesymbolsstix}{"EF}{largesymbolsstix}{"15}
\newcommand{\newbrak}[2]{\genfrac{\lbrbrak}{\rbrbrak}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\[
\newbrak{k}{m} = 
\lBrace A, B \rBrace = \sum_{k=1}^3
  \biggl\lBrack \frac{\partial A}{\partial q_k}\biggr\rBrack
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steven, actually you've answered at the same time i discovered it vas only a "formality vice", and that it was sufficient to change the `largesymbol` name. Anyway this solves the problem so best answer for you! `:-)`