# Automatically scale resize-able delimiters from imported font \left \right

Tags: fonts, delimiters, stix

I am using the amsmath package and fonts, but would like to import a few delimiters from stix.  Following the instructions here: [How to use only selected math symbols of the STIX fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254618/how-to-use-only-selected-math-symbols-of-the-stix-fonts)

I can import the desired delimiters.  However, I would like to automatically scale those delimiters according to the size of the interior math expression (the commands \left{ and \right} come to mind).  I know I can manually change their size with commands like \bigl\lBrace, but it is important that it can happen automatically (as done with the \left and \right  commands).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolstix}{LS2}{stixex}{m} {n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBrace}{\mathopen}{largesymbolstix}{"E8}{largesymbols}{"0E}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBrace}{\mathclose}{largesymbolstix}{"E9}{largesymbols}{"0F}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrbrak}{\mathopen}{largesymbolstix}{"EE}{largesymbols}{"14}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrbrak}{\mathclose}{largesymbolstix}{"EF}{largesymbols}{"15}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lParen}{\mathopen}{largesymbolstix}{"DE}{largesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rParen}{\mathclose}{largesymbolstix}{"DF}{largesymbols}{"03}


\begin{document}

$\left\lBrace \begin{array}{cc}x & y\\y& z\end{array} \right\rBrace$

\end{document}
```

If I remove the \left and \right commands, my output has the correct braces, but not appropriately sized.  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I've taken the liberty of reformatting your code.  You can do this yourself by highlighting the code block (by mousing over), then clicking on the `{}` icon above the question box.

Comment: You need `largesymbolstix` in both places of every line.

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer to `largesymbolstix` in both places.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter % <---- Don't forget
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\makeatother
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolstix}{LS2}{stixex}{m} {n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lBrace}{\mathopen}{largesymbolstix}{"E8}{largesymbolstix}{"0E}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rBrace}{\mathclose}{largesymbolstix}{"E9}{largesymbolstix}{"0F}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrbrak}{\mathopen}{largesymbolstix}{"EE}{largesymbolstix}{"14}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrbrak}{\mathclose}{largesymbolstix}{"EF}{largesymbolstix}{"15}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lParen}{\mathopen}{largesymbolstix}{"DE}{largesymbolstix}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rParen}{\mathclose}{largesymbolstix}{"DF}{largesymbolstix}{"03}

\begin{document}

$
\left\lBrace \begin{array}{cc}x & y\\y& z\end{array} \right\rBrace
\left\lbrbrak \begin{array}{cc}x & y\\y& z\end{array} \right\rbrbrak
\left\lParen \begin{array}{cc}x & y\\y& z\end{array} \right\rParen
$

\end{document}
```

[image]